# Call Databricks Api from IdentityServer4 client

Tags: asp.net-core, databricks, openid-connect, identityserver4, azure-databricks

I am using IdentityServer4 with Microsoft Entra Id as my external login provider. I want to access Databricks api via IdentityServer4.

I have registered IdentityServer4 in Entra and configured Databricks scope (user_impersonation) in Api permission tab. I have created service principal in Azure Databricks with IdentityServer4 client id.
In code, I have added "[databricks app id]/.default" for openid connect scope in both client and IdentityServer4 when configuring openid connect.
When I receive access token after the user logins from the client, access token doesn't have the data_bricks scope(user_impersonation) added.
I am getting unauthorized error when calling the databricks api.
Need help to resolve this issue and call databricks api from identityserver4 client